# How do other devices outside of my router connect to my server

Tags: node.js, http, server

Sorry for a silly question, I am a neophyte in this topic. But how do I get other users to interact with a server I've written? Does it have something to do with my router configurations or listen method in Node.js?

```
server.listen(3000, "my ip", () => {
    console.log("Listening to requests!");
});
```

Up:
I updated router settings in Port Forwarding, added Internal Host IP Address, specified protocol along with internal and external ports. Then I checked whether port forwarding is working on https://www.portchecktool.com/, everything seems alright but I only get response from the server on my mobile device. On PC I get "'my ip' refused to connect". Also, I write public_ip:3000, for instance 40.183.241.13:3000

Comment: They should try to connect to your IP address and port? for example 192.0.0.1:3000

Comment: On my devices it works when I specify ip:3000, I get a response from the server. Though for others it doesn't. I though because of NAT request should first come to my router then to computer, but I might be mistaken

Comment: A firewall might be blocking access to that port?

Comment: Tried turning off firewall, not effect

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: win64 if you refer to OS